# Create streaming server at home like Opera Unite

Tags: software-rec, streaming

Opera Unite is discontinued, but it had some nice applications like media server. You could point a folder with movies and other users, who know some password and address could have watched all the shared movies. Can you suggest some similar program to do that?

Answer (score 1):

vlc.

It supports all the major formats and is free.

http://www.videolan.org/

Comment: Sorry, but cant find any instructions on how to create stream and than open some of the streamed files from another computer..

Comment: VLC is a great app, but it has nothing to do with what Opera Unite did.

Comment: Well it isn't designed to be easy or friendly or social but you can still stream arbitrary media.